# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Identity Form Authentication with Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory

I am using VS Professional 2019. I create a new project with an individual authentication template. Am I able to make some changes and make it work with Active Directory? Everything I was able to find was too old and didn't work for me. I would appreciate a guide on how to achieve it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to download nuget package using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate. Add NTLM authentication to your mvc pipeline:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddNegotiate(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, op => { 
            op.Events = new NegotiateEvents();
            op.EventsType = typeof(YourClassToEnhanceAuthLogic);
});
```

This code adds NTLM negotiation which actually authenticates users in AD.
If you deploy to IIS, don't forget to enable windows authentication. It also works well with Kestrel web server.
You can find more on NTLM authentication [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4559)